# Definition of "2 functions agree"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, terminology

When study about Measure theory, I usually come up with the phrase "2 functions agree" but I can't find this definition of "agreement of functions".

Could you please explain what it is ?

Comment: They take the same values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't provide any context or examples, I can only hope this applies to your question:

Given two functions $f,g\colon X\to Y$ we say that $f$ and $g$ agree on $A\subseteq X$ if $f(a)=g(a)$ for all $a\in A$.